# plt.imshow() shows no color given a three-channel image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to implementing K-means algorithms and apply it on images,
so the output image kind of has the effect of image segmentation,
but after the computation is done, both plt.imshow() and put.imwrite() give a grayscale image.

print(image.shape) gives (250, 143, 3) for my test image, so that means I'm manipulating a three-channel image right?

I have tried tricks like int, float, multiplication and division by 255, but none of them works.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_distance(a, b):
    return (a - b) @ (a - b).T

def update_label(centroids, label, image):

    for y in range(image.shape[0]):
        for x in range(image.shape[1]):
            distance = np.ndarray((centroids.shape[0], ))
            
            for i in range(centroids.shape[0]):
                distance[i] = get_distance(image[y, x], centroids[i])

            label[y, x] = np.argmin(distance)

    return label

def update_centroids(centroids, label, image):

    for i in range(centroids.shape[0]):
        index = np.where(label == i)
        centroids[i] = np.mean(image[index])

    return centroids

NUMBER_OF_CENTROIDS = 3

image = np.array(plt.imread('./dataset/marina.jpg'))
centroids = np.ndarray((NUMBER_OF_CENTROIDS, 3))

for i in range(centroids.shape[0]):
    index_x = np.random.randint(0, image.shape[1], 1)
    index_y = np.random.randint(0, image.shape[0], 1)
    centroids[i] = image[index_y, index_x]

label = np.full((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), -1)

for i in range(5):
    label = update_label(centroids, label, image)
    centroids = update_centroids(centroids, label, image)

for y in range(image.shape[0]):
    for x in range(image.shape[1]):
        image[y, x] = centroids[label[y, x]]

print(image.shape)
        
plt.imshow(image)
plt.imsave('./dataset/marina_test.jpg', image)
```

Comment: Try printing `image.max()` and `image.mean()` and `image.min()` and `image.dtype`.

Comment: what is the shape of `centroids[label[y, x]]`?

Comment: I got (205, 52, 94.09675524475524, uint8) for max(), min(), mean(), and dtype, which looks fine though?

Comment: @LiorCohen It's (3, ), a 1D array with three colors.

Comment: and what is the type? integers? and do you get 3 different numbers?

Comment: Oh, I got three identical numbers; no wonder the output is grayscale. Maybe the problem lies in the way I calculate the mean for clusters. Thanks for pointing that out!